# Default Fetch group in MongoDB - dataneucleus

Tags: mongodb, lazy-loading, jdo, datanucleus

I use datanucleus and MongoDB for storing my objects. I detected problems with the lazy loading.

One on My class is :

```java
    public class Member  implements Serializable{
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @PrimaryKey
            @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
            private String key;

            private String username; 
            @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup="true",dependent="true")
            private Parameter param = null;
    }
```

And the code for retrieving this object is :

```java
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    Member member = pm.getObjectById(Member.class,"MyID");
    tx.commit();
    //if I check here, the field "param" is null.
```

When I check, the field "param" is null. However, I set the meta data to load by default the param. Maybe the driver MongoDB-JDO doesn't support the metadata "defaultFetchGroup".

Could you tell me what happens?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the situation is "here" (outside the transaction) depends totally on the [object lifecycle](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/object_lifecycle.html) and what persistence options you have enabled. That link defines it. Likely the object is HOLLOW, so fields have been unloaded and you didnt set "datanucleus.RetainValues"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I create another question about datanucleus, maybe you could help me again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955028/recursive-relation-between-objects