# ArrayList of super class type

Tags: java, mongodb, jdo, datanucleus

I use mongodb-datanucleus in my project. I configure my jdoconfig.xml as follow :

```
    <persistence-manager-factory name="mongodb-factory">
    <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory" />
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="mongodb:localhost/test" />
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="mongodb" />
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" value="username" />
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" value="psw" />
    <property name="javax.jdo.option.Optimistic" value="false" />
    <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true" /> 
    <property name="datanucleus.DetachAllOnCommit" value="true" />
    <property name="datanucleus.DetachOnClose" value="true" />
    </persistence-manager-factory>
```

I create super class :

```
    @PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
    public class Definition implements Serializable {
        private String label;
    }
```

I create a sub class :

```
    @PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
    public class SubDefinition extends Definition implements Serializable {
        private String label;
    }
```

Then, I create a class that store an array list of Definition :

```
    @PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
    public class Master implements Serializable {
        @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup="true")
        @Element(dependent = "true")
        private List<Definition> subDef;
    }
```

My List of Definition can contain objects of type Definition or SubDefinition. I create a Master object and persist it.

The problem happens when I retrieve my object form the database :

```
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    Query query = pm.newQuery();
    query.setClass(Master.class);
    Collection<Master> masterList = (Collection<Master>)query.execute();
    tx.commit();
```

If I don't restart my server, the code retrieves the correct object, my "subDef" list is correctly loaded. However, after I restart my server-database, this object is not correctly loaded. The variable "subDef" contains an empty array. It should contains 2 sub elements.

This problem happens after each time I restart my server. After, I restart some code make the array empty. It's not one of my code.

If I check into the database, the both sub elements are present but not linking any more with their parent. Directly after I persist the object, the relation are correctly present into the DB.

Graphical representation of the stored object :

```
    Master
      ->subDef
        ->Definition (children 1)
        ->Definition (children 2)
```

Why do I have this problem? Maybe creating a list of super class is not allow?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: As already said in the comments of my answer (to the original question) the log is there to help you debug your problem, telling you what is being persisted and when. That is the way of debugging issues

Comment: The log of Datanucleus of mongodb?

Comment: I detect that after the tx.commit, the logger of dataneucleus display an update message of my Master object. But I shouldn't because I only do a request, not any more. Here is the message : [DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - Updating object StateManager[pc=model.Budget@27f2182c, lifecycle=P_NONTRANS_DIRTY] as { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50810e203004e185f33c46ae"}

Answer (score 0):

All in the docs, as per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/fetchgroup.html#static
section on "Fetch Depth".

Comment: I edidted my question. I set the setMaxDepthSize to -1, but I still have the problem.

Comment: There is no such setMaxDepthSize method, perhaps you mean _something else_

Comment: I used that code : 'PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
  pm.getFetchPlan().setMaxFetchDepth(-1)'

Comment: You have recursive relations and missed the part referring to it on that page. The log tells you what is being detached so you can debug it. Works for the JDO TCK

Comment: Thanks. I change my question, because since I created my question, I go deeper in my code and found the real problem. The problem  : I store an ArrayList of super class type. Could you read again my question? And tell me your feedback please? Thanks a lot